# Removing multiple items from a Java JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable, defaulttablemodel

So I have a default table model that is populated by an Object I created.  One of the Objects is Name, with three other string properties of the object.  I have a button that performs an action, now when this button performs this action I need to loop through all of the items in that DefaultTableModel and remove any and all items that have the same value in column 0 as the object chosen. So the problem I have is this will only remove one item with that value(Name).  I need this code to remove all of the items that contain the same string value as column 0.

```
                int nRow = suggestedAcTableModel.getRowCount() - 1;

                for (int i = 0; i < nRow; i++) {

                    String acNameStr = suggestedAcTableModel.getValueAt(i, 0).toString();

                    if (acNameStr.equals(acName)) {

                        suggestedAcTableModel.removeRow(i);
                    }
                }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are wanting to search each column for the value and then delete the entire row if the value is found then see below.

```
for (int i = 0; i < suggestedAcTableModel.getRowCount(); i++) {
    for(int j = 0; j < suggestedAcTableModel.getColumnCount(); j++){
        String acNameStr = suggestedAcTableModel.getValueAt(i, j).toString();
        if (acNameStr.equals(acName)) { 
           suggestedAcTableModel.removeRow(i);
           j = suggestedAcTableModel.getColumnCount();
           i--;
        }
    }
}
```